# how to connect ELCB single phase

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

Please find the attached diagram. Is this ELCB + MCB connection is correct for a single phase house ?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: Since you're referring to it as an ELCB and not a GFCI I'm assuming you're in a country where the standard practice is to protect the entire house from Earch-Leakage/Ground-Faults and not individual circuits/outlets. In that case, yes, this looks correct.

Comment: thanks for your reply. and both ELCB and RCD are available in market. BTW in case of Residual Current Device (RCD), is the same wiring diagram is correct ? Just replace ELCB with RCD.